# Migrating existing Flex 4.x projects to Apache Flex 4.x

Tags: apache-flex

I've been tasked with maintaining some existing flex 4.6 projects and am wanting to future proof them for the latest browsers. Should I move the projects over to Apache flex? If so what do I need to do to make these existing projects compatible with Apache flex?

Answer (score 2):

**No**, you don't need to migrate these projects to Apache Flex.

Flex 4.6 projects can still be built and deployed; they just don't have the latest SDK changes.  Your projects will remain compatible with future Flash Player versions.

The only reason to update to Apache Flex at this point is if you need features introduced in a later version of the Flex SDK.

Comment: Cool, good to know, what about IDE's. Do you think its worthwhile switching to Jetbrains?

Comment: I don't know anything about Jetbrains.  Maybe ask that in a discussion forum?

Answer (score 2):

Recent versions of the Apache Flex SDK have newer features, a large number of bug fixes, have been tested with the latest version of Flash Player, and in general have better performance and consume less memory than Adobe Flex 4.6.

So while Apache Flex is not required to run in the latest browsers you stil may want to consider moving to Apache Flex for these reasons.

Answer (score 1):

My experience is with Flex/AIR desktop apps, I migrated using the Apache Flex installer to download latest SDK and AIR, then in the IDE you need to add the new SDK and select it. I did not had bugs or problems when I upgraded to latest versions(but you may encounter bugs or differences so you need to do some testing)